# Page not found (404) is reporting

Tags: python, django, django-urls

There is 'Page not found(404)' error that has been showing since yesterday but before that everything was working great. The program was running on the same URL path but now it isn't, please tell your suggestions. Thank You!

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from Platform import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/Home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('/blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in Portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

/admin/
/Home/ [name='home']
/blog/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: You dont have empty path like '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Removed the starting **/** from the URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Please read this [URLS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example)

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    
]
```

You should have a path where it is empty, then it will lead you main page.